# How to activate windows server 2003 via ISO?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003

The problem is windows server 2003 asks activation with no option.
I tried to do [THIS](https://networksupportsolution.blogspot.com/2015/02/windows-server-2003-r2-standard-crack.html) with registry option. Now I got just login screen, activation window doesn't work.

I am finding tool ISO to activate windows.

Comment: Windows Server 2003 is end-of-life for so long now. I would highly recommend to migrate the server to a newer version of Windows. No updates will come out for this OS so having this install connected to the internet will basically invite hackers to steal your data.

Answer (score 0):

From [O'Reilly - Windows Server Cookbook

Activating Windows Server 2003](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-server-cookbook/0596006330/ch02s02.html)

> **Using a graphical user interface**
>
> From the Start menu, select All Programs → Activate Windows.
>
> Select whether you want to activate by phone or over the Internet.
>
> **Using a command-line interface**
>
> The following command opens the Activation wizard described in the
>   previous section:
>
> ```
> %systemroot%\system32\oobe\msoobe /a
> ```
>
> There are no options that can activate the computer silently from the
>   command line.
>
> Using VBScript
>
> ```
>     ' This code activates a Windows Server 2003 system. ' ------ SCRIPT CONFIGURATION ------ strComputer = "." boolActivateOnline =
> True ' If this is true, boolActivateOffline should ' be false
> boolActivateOffline = False ' If this is true, boolActivateOnline
> should ' be false strOfflineConfirmationCode = "1234-5678" ' if
> Activating offline, you need ' specify a confirmation code ' ------
> END CONFIGURATION --------- set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" &
> strComputer & "\root\cimv2") set colWPA =
> objWMI.InstancesOf("Win32_WindowsProductActivation") for each objWPA
> in colWPA WScript.Echo "Activation Settings:" Wscript.Echo "
> Activation Required: " & objWPA.ActivationRequired Wscript.Echo "
> Caption: " & objWPA.Caption Wscript.Echo " Description: " &
> objWPA.Description Wscript.Echo " Notification On: " &
> objWPA.IsNotificationOn ...
> ```